# Dummy variable trap, does it matter which dummy column I delete?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, dummy-variable

I've just learned about dummy variables and about it's trap. So let's assume I have a categorical column with 3 categories in it, for example:

```
Dog
Cat
Bear
```

I split it to 3 separated columns, IsDog, IsCat, IsBear with 0/1 in it, so I can use it in my model. But they say number of dummy columns should always be (number_of_categories - 1).
So should I delete the last one (in this case IsBear), or it actually doesn't matter, just take away random one?

Comment: This question is more akin to CrossValidated. Any ways, what changes is the interpretation of your coefficients. If you're using methods like Random Forests it doesn't matter. For a better answer look there, it probably has been asked multiple times.

Comment: From a model perspective, it doesn't matter.  However, if you care about what you see in your analytics (meaning, you want to see Bear/Dog) you may want to delete a specific column.

Comment: A better way to search for explanations is the term "One Hot Encoding", saying that only one of your categories is "hot" (true) and the rest aren't (or false/0). It breaks down to the difference between "IsBear/IsCat/IsDog" vs "IsBear/IsCat/Neither". In terms of actual informative value, there's no difference between the two regimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have Pandas do it automatically for you, for each categorical column, as follows.

Note that it will automatically prefix the new column name (e.g. categorical variable 'Dog' with 3 categories will give two new columns: Dog_1, Dog_2), and it will drop the original column ('Dog'). With the `drop first` option it will give you k-1 dummy columns for a column with k categories (i.e. The column Dog with 3 categories becomes 2 – not 3 – dummy columns, as above, and as per your question).

```py
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['cat_var_1', 'cat_var_2'], drop_first=True)
```